# Data extract widget - Flex

Tags: data, arcgis-flex-viewer, widget

I have successfully created a data extract widget. It works great.

I would now like to be able to set a limit say of 5000sqm or something.

I have seen other sites do this. They have a message pop up saying:

> you have exceeded the size limitation, reduce your area of interest.

Looking for some sugestions on how to achieve this.

here is some examples of sites that do what I would like to achieve

http://www.myplan.ie/viewer/

http://maps.aucklandcouncil.govt.nz/aucklandcouncilviewer/

We are an ESRI site, using Flex 3.6 viewer and Flex SDK 4.6. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: At what point in the process does the "exceeded limitation" message pop up? Do you have an example URL of a site that does that?

Comment: seamless (or the national map, does it)